# (Biopython) how can I increase the number of articles found using Entrez.esearch(retmax=N)?

Tags: biopython

I want to extract articles based on a key term and a specific period using biopython.
However, for some reason, no matter how big the number I put in "retmax", the max number is 9999.
When I looked up Pubmed manually, the number of articles found is way different, more than 9999.

```
from Bio import Entrez
from io import StringIO
import csv

# Set email and API key (replace 'youremail' and 'yourapikey' with your own)
Entrez.email = 'banana@gmail' #just dummy
Entrez.api_key = 'banana' #just dummy

# Define search terms and time window
search_term = 'cancer'
start_date = '2015/01/01'
end_date = '2016/08/30'

# Define search query
query = f'{search_term}[Title/Abstract] AND ("{start_date}"[Date - Publication] : "{end_date}"[Date - Publication])'

# Search PUBMED using the query
handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed', term=query, retmax=10000)
record = Entrez.read(handle)
id_list = record['IdList']
len(id_list)
```

Please help me how to get the exact number of articles extracted from Pubmed using biopython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the [`ncbi esearch`](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#chapter4.ESearch) documentation that is posted in the [`biopython esearch`](https://biopython.org/docs/1.76/api/Bio.Entrez.html#Bio.Entrez.esearch) documentation has to say about about increasing the number of `retmax` to more than `10000` records in `PubMed`:

> retmax
>
> Total number of UIDs from the retrieved set to be shown in the XML
> output (default=20). By default, ESearch only includes the first 20
> UIDs retrieved in the XML output. If `usehistory` is set to 'y', the
> remainder of the retrieved set will be stored on the History server;
> otherwise these UIDs are lost. Increasing `retmax` allows more of the
> retrieved UIDs to be included in the XML output, up to a maximum of
> 10,000 records.
>
> To retrieve more than 10,000 UIDs from databases other than PubMed,
> submit multiple esearch requests while incrementing the value of
> `retstart` (see Application 3). For PubMed, ESearch can only retrieve
> the first 10,000 records matching the query. To obtain more than
> 10,000 PubMed records, consider using `<EDirect>` that contains
> additional logic to batch PubMed search results automatically so that
> an arbitrary number can be retrieved.

You can try to use the section **"9.16.2 Searching for and downloading abstracts using the history"** in the [`biopython cookbook`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec172) to get all the records in chunks of `10000` using the the `restart` and `retmax` arguments.